# How can I combine two queries that filter two lists of A & B objects respectively by whether they're linked to a C object?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have three tables: Alpha, Bravo, & Charlie. Charlie has a many-to-one relationship to both Alpha and Bravo, but any given row in Charlie will only be linked to an Alpha *or* a Bravo, never both. That is, table Charlie has foreign keys linking to the primary key of table Alpha and to the primary key of table Bravo, but for any given row in Charlie at least one of those foreign keys will be null.

I have a list of primary keys from Alpha & a list of primary keys from Bravo. I'd like to filter both lists to remove any rows that are linked to by a row in Charlie.

I'm currently doing this in two queries:

```
SELECT A.a_pk
FROM Alpha A
WHERE A.a_pk IN (1, 2, 5, 17, etc)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT C.c_pk FROM Charlie C WHERE C.a_pk = A.a_pk)

SELECT B.b_pk
FROM Bravo B
WHERE B.b_pk IN (1, 3, 5, 14, etc)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT C.c_pk FROM Charlie C WHERE C.b_pk = B.b_pk)
```

Can these two queries can be combined, and if so is it worth doing so?

Remember that if `C.a_pk` has a value, `C.b_pk` will be `NULL`, and vice versa. Alpha & Bravo are *not* symmetrical tables, but the other columns aren't used in these queries, since I just need to filter an existing set of Alpha & Bravo objects I already have all the data for.

The combined query would need to work in both SQL Server 2008 and in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two queries can be combined (see below), whether they should or not is something only you can determine - why do you want to?

**Combined Query**

```
SELECT A.a_pk, NULL AS b_pk
FROM   Alpha A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       Charlie C
       ON ( C.a_pk = A.a_pk )
WHERE  C.a_pk IS NULL
--AND    A.a_pk IN ( 1, 2, 3, 17 )
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, B.b_pk
FROM   Bravo B
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       Charlie C
       ON ( C.b_pk = B.b_pk )
WHERE  C.b_pk IS NULL
--AND    B.b_pk IN ( 1, 3, 5, 14 )
```

**Results**:

```
|   A_PK |   B_PK |
|--------|--------|
|      5 | (null) |
|      3 | (null) |
| (null) |      5 |
| (null) |      3 |
| (null) |      1 |
```

[Oracle - SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53535/1)

[SQL Server - SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d2fb/2)